# Is there a Java equivalent of Adobe Flash CS?

Tags: java, flash

Are there any UI interfaces for Java that are similar to Adobe's Flash CS series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you`re looking for something like flex in java to develop rich internet aplications take a look for java FX